# angular-cli globally installation failure

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am trying to install `angular-cli` globally but getting these errors.What to do?

```
C:\Users\Jahidul>npm install -g angular-cli

npm WARN registry Using stale data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ because the h
ost is inaccessible -- are you offline?

npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been renamed to
 @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/micromatch failed, reason:
 getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:8080

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jahidul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-30T14_57_5
6_218Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my internet connection was not stable.Now everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the instructions mentioned on [this site](https://cli.angular.io/), you will find out that the command

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

should be replaced by

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

which is also mentioned in the error. Retry using the new command.

Comment: Now getting these errors

C:\Users\Jahidul>npm install -g @angular/cli

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN

npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN

npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: get
addrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:8080

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jahidul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-30T15_36_0
4_880Z-debug.log

Comment: @JahidPathan -- Please post what's in `C:\Users\Jahidul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-06-30T1‌​5_36_0 4_880Z-debug.log`!

Answer (score 0):

If you get the same error and you are behind a corporate network, then you need to change the config to add proxy as below:

1. Go to node.js install location in command prompt and type below command:

   `npm  config edit --g`
2. Add below lines at the end of the file:

   `registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
   strict-ssl=false
   proxy=http://proxy.YOURCOMPANYNAME.com:8080`
3. Then execute the npm install command:

   `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`